# Locus of point on complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis

The loci of a point $p(z)$ in the complex plane satisfying  $\left|z+\frac 1z\right|=2$ are two circles $C$ and $C'$ . These circles have equation?
While attempting a solution, I took $z=x+iy$, then try to make an equation in $x$ and $y$ which can be factored into the equation of two circles but I am ended in $(x^2+y^2)^2 -2x^2 -6y^2+1=0$. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Your calculation up to $(x^2+y^2)^2-2x^2-6y^2+1=0$ is fine. Now this can be rewritten as 
\begin{eqnarray*}
(x^2+y^2-1)^2-4y^2=0 \\
(x^2+y^2+2y-1)(x^2+y^2-2y-1)=0
\end{eqnarray*}
Now each bracket will give a solution $\color{blue}{x^2+(y \pm 1)^2=2}$. So the solution is two circles center $(0,\pm 1)$ of radius $ \sqrt{2}$.

[image]

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/e37y6hja4s